# Change owner of files uploaded by vsFTPd

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I installed a vsftpd server and created an account for one FTPuser. This FTPuser uploads files in another user directory (user1), and this user1 runs a program that uses these files. I have added both users to groups FTPuser and user1 and changed the permissions to 775, however the program requires that files are owned by user1.
I tried:

`sudo setfacl -m d:user1:rwx /home/user1/serverfiles`

and

`sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:user1:rw,g:user1:rw,o::r /home/user1/serverfiles`

but nothing seems to change, files uploaded are still owned by FTPuser

Comment: Did you run `sudo chown -R user1 /home/user1/serverfiles` to change the current files as that command won't change those files already created?

Comment: I did, but the owner is still FTPuser

Comment: I wonder why that is?

Comment: I found those commands in another thread, installed acl and ran the commands. Maybe its because i have bind mounted the directory of user1 to FTPuser

`mount --bind /home/user1/serverfiles /home/FTPuser/workspace`
But i did run the command for both directories.
Also, `setfacl --help` works

Comment: Please what version of Ubuntu is this, why would you need to install `acl`?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, isn't setfacl a command of acl?

Comment: Yes it is but it should be preinstalled but perhaps it isn't in Ubuntu Tahr!

Comment: Tbh im not sure whether it was installed or not, i made a typo on the command and ended up installing it either way.

Comment: If so it would have said pkg already installed!

Comment: How bad of an idea would it be to set up a cron job to run every 1-2 mins setting ownership according to my needs?